# React context state not being updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I have a basic react context, similar to below:

```
function IdProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [id, setId] = useState("DEFAULT_ID")
  
  return (
    <IdContext.Provider value={{ id, setId }}>
      {children}
    </IdContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I'm wrapping all of my routes with this provider, and have one component as below which I want to use to update the Id:

```
function UpdateForm() {
  const { id, setId } = useId() // wrapper for the IdContext
 
  const moveToDisplay = (newId: string) => {
    setId(newId)
    window.location.href = "/display/" + id
  }

  return (
    <>
      <span onClick={() => moveToDisplay("NEW_ID")}>
       Update and redirect
      </span>
    </>
  )
}
```

Upon redirecting, this component is used:

```
function DisplayId(): JSX.Element {
  const { id } = useId()

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = id
  }, [id])

  return (
    <>
      {id}
    </>
  )
}
```

The issue is, the initial `setId(newId)` doesn't update the state, so when `window.location.href = "/display/" + id` is called it redirects to `/display/DEFAULT_ID`, and the `DisplayId` component still uses the `DEFAULT_ID` value when rendering. From my understanding the `useState` is asynchronous, so I'm not entirely sure how I should approach this problem. I've tried adding a 5 second timeout after `setId` is called, but the value of `id` is still the default value.

EDIT - SOLVED

Figured out the issue and it was fairly unrelated. I was using a single constant (e.g. `DEFAULT_ID`) to initialise state in various places, without realising that React checks for referential equality when updating / re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

useContext provides the ability to pass properties through the react chain of components. So change your provider to this & make sure it's exporting

```
<IdContext.Provider value={id}>
```

then in your child you can update that by importing the Context:

```
import IdContext from './IdProvider'
```

and useContext:

```
const [context, setContext] = useContext(IdContext)
```

then set it with the new value:

```
const moveToDisplay = (newId: string) => {
   setContext(newId)
   window.location.href = "/display/" + newId
}
```

After that you import it in the same fashion through your DisplayId and just use the value

Comment: I've tried that, and it redirects to the correct URL, but the id is still `DEFAULT_VALUE` when it gets used within the `useEffect` of the `DisplayId` component.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Do you have a useContext() in your DisplayId?

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in the code (updated now), yeah the `DisplayId` uses the same context, and is wrapped in the same `IdProvider`.

Comment: Cool, if you want to do it through the url you'll need to do a `window.location.href` to get it & get the id at the end. If you're wanting to do it through your `Context.Provider`, this is probably the best way, you should use `setContext() & useContext()`

Comment: I was doing it via URL before, but it's not just the ID I want to pass, so using context makes more sense. I'm already doing your second suggestion, I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Here's a really good article on passing information around using useContext: https://dev.to/efearas/how-to-usecontext-and-set-value-of-context-in-child-components-in-3-steps-3j9h . I'm going to update the answer a bit to reflect the correction:)

Comment: I appreciate all the help, discovered it was actually related to my use of constants though.. doh!